# No route matches [GET] "/sign_in"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, devise

Set up Authentication with AngularJS and Ruby on Rails. Try to do under this article https://www.airpair.com/ruby-on-rails/posts/authentication-with-angularjs-and-ruby-on-rails. But when run the test with rspec have the same error

```
Authentication login with valid inputs
     Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches [GET] "/sign_in"
```

In rake routes have:

```
                  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                            Controller#Action
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)               devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)               devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session GET    /users/sign_out(.:format)              devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)              devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)          devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)         devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)              devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)              devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                       devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)               devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                  devise/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)                       devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                       devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                       devise/registrations#destroy
       user_confirmation POST   /users/confirmation(.:format)          devise/confirmations#create
   new_user_confirmation GET    /users/confirmation/new(.:format)      devise/confirmations#new
                         GET    /users/confirmation(.:format)          devise/confirmations#show
                    root GET    /                                      devise/sessions#new
               user_root GET    /persons/profile(.:format)             persons#profile
               next_page GET    /index(.:format)                       persons#index
                         GET    /omniauth/:provider/callback(.:format) devise_token_auth/omniauth_callbacks#redirect_callbacks
```

Comment: Actually it is sending a `GET` request which should be `POST` on form submit and also the path is `"/sign_in"` which should be `"/users/sign_in"`

Answer (score 0):

As your `routes` say...you need to use `/users/sign_in` with `GET` request.
You are using `/sign_in` which **doesn't exist**...
you can directly use `new_user_session_path`
if you actually want to use /sign_in,edit your routes and add this

```
  get 'sign_in' => 'devise/sessions#new'
```